# How to root the Droid Maxx with 4.4.4 KitKat

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid

Is there a way to root the Motorola Droid Maxx (Android 4.4.4 KitKat)? It doesn't even support the ESPN app as-is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to root droid running 4.4.4 KitKat](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/how-to-root-droid-running-4-4-4-kitkat)

Comment: Related http://forums.androidcentral.com/motorola-droid-maxx/580269-how-do-i-fully-root-motorola-droid-maxx-android-4-4-4-a.html#post4682808

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of rooting apps avialble for rooting kitkat mobiles.. The apps like Framaroot, King Root, VRoot and so on.. for more information [check this out](http://www.3ptechies.com/mobile/android/root-without-pc-apk.html)..

Comment: Tyvm! Hopefully one of these will work